# Printing values on the form

Tags: vba, excel

I have some values that are stored in a Collection and an array. I want to display these values on a form. The values in the dictionary and the array are basically values that are stored as messages to the user which he needs to know after the execution of a macro. I tried doing so using a text box but it does not come out so neatly and the text that goes into the textbox needs to be appended each time. Also, since the values are stored in an array and I iterate through the array, the text comes out repeated instead of just the value. What I mean is in for the second value of the array, I need only the second value to be displayed but, it comes out appended with the first value. Is there any other way to do this? Or am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1
This is the code that I have written till now
warningBox is the text box
totalRows,sheetArray, dummyArray are all arrays
errorCollection is the collection

```
For arrayIterator = 0 To UBound(totalRows)
    If totalRows(arrayIterator) > 500 Then
        warningBox.Text = " More values for" & sheetArray(arrayIterator)
    End If
Next arrayIterator
arrayIterator = 0
For collectionIndex = 1 To errorCollection.Count
    dummyArray = errorCollection(collectionIndex)
    If UBound(dummyArray) > 0 Then
        warningBox.Text = warningBox.Text & sheetArray(collectionIndex - 1) & "has value"
        For arrayIterator = 0 To UBound(dummyArray)
            warningBox.Text = warningBox.Text & dummyArray(arrayIterator)
        Next arrayIterator
    End If
Next collectionIndex
```

Edit 2
The contents of the collection are as below
Key : A string value
Value : A variant array

So I want to display the following
1. The elements of an array which is not in the collection (totalRows)
2. The elements of an array which is in the collection.(dummyArray)

Comment: Show some code to get some help , please.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have added the code that I have written till now

Comment: you need to display only the value of the array or the collection? * just trying to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this, which appends the collection item's value to the existing text within the textbox:

```
warningBox.Text = warningBox.Text & sheetArray(collectionIndex - 1) & "has value"
```

Do this, which assigns the textbox's `.Text` property based on the collection item's value:

```
warningBox.Text = sheetArray(collectionIndex - 1) & "has value"
```

**Update**

This is a shot in the dark, but I think maybe this will do what you want, if I am guessing correctly you want to take the textbox and first append the item from the Collection. So you will have something like:

`"Text box text Collection.Item(1) has value"`

Then you want to append ALL of the items from the Array, so you will result with:

`"Text box text Collection.Item(1) has value: Array(0), Array(1), Array(2), Array(3)"

To do this, instead of iterating the array (this is the problem!) use the `Join` function to coerce the array in to a delimited string and only do the append once for the entire array:

```
If UBound(dummyArray) > 0 Then
    warningBox.Text = warningBox.Text & sheetArray(collectionIndex - 1) & "has value"

        warningBox.Text = warningBox.Text & Join(dummyArray, ", ")

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Well the thing is since I use the assignment of the warningBox.Text several places, the final output does not include all the text that I want on the text box. Hence I am appending the previous value.

Comment: OK. Well clearly you know enough about VBA to be able to debug this on your own then, this is a pretty elementary problem, but without seeing more of your code and a better description of what you want (I'm the one answering you, I should not be the one asking a dozen questions to find out what you're actually trying to do), then you're on your own.

Comment: Hey, apologies if my question did not come out clear. The thing is I did not want to post unnecessary code. The above code is the only place that I use the textbox and "textbox.append". Setting this multiple times does not give out any output at all on the textbox. Hence, I appended it at every place that I use since I need display values from both the dictionary and the array. But, I guess as you say this is an elementary problem. Since, I was unable to fix this I thought of asking.

Comment: Here's the issue: You still have not adequately described the problem.  There appear to be some circumstances where you need to append to the existing text, and others where you do not want to append.  I presume there's some base/un-changing text that you want to include always, etc... Better description of what you're trying to accomplish, along with an example of some of your array & collection data would be helpful. It would also be very helpful to include some screenshots (since you don't have enough rep to include images, post them to imgur.com and add the links to your original post).

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here... see revision above.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the tips. But, I would like to ask you something probably very basic. How would you display lot of data to the user after a macro has run on the XL? I mean these are like warning messages.But,there is a chance there might be a lot of them. I am not allowed to add another worksheet which is like a report. All I need to do is display this data. I tried the join, does not work because of "Type mismatch" error

Comment: I made a revision to my revision, it should be `Join(dummyArray, ", ")` and as long as `dummyArray` is a one-dimensional array, I think that should avoid the mismatch error.  LMK if that doesn't work.